# Linux port open locally, but not externally

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-ec2

Port is open locally, but not externally

Neo4j is a graph database with a browser and REST interface.I need to start a second instance of neo4j server. I would like to run the process a user with normal privileges.

The first instance of neo4j opens the default port for neo4j, 7474, and runs and HTTP server on it. I can reach it with a Web browser from another machine. That's great.

The second instance is configured to use a different port, 7484. I can start the server and reach it locally:

```
 >lynx http://localhost:7484
```

That's great too.

However, if I use another machine and try to browse `http://my-neo4j-server:7484`, the browser times-out and never establishes a connection.

If I run netstat on the server, it shows that it is listening on that port.

```
 >netstat -tulpn
```

...

```
tcp6  0  0   :::7484   :::*  LISTEN  8552/java
```

I tried:

```
  >sudo ufw disable
```

I checked IP tables:

```
>sudo iptables -L
```

and there are no entries in the tables.

What am I failing to do?

Note: I'm running the Amazon Linux AMI on ec2.

Comment: Did you intend to use IPv6 exclusively, not the more common IPv4? If you want to go IPv6, you need a special DNS setup with AAA records.

Comment: Did you open the Amazon Security Group for the new port?

Comment: @laurent. You were correct. I forgot that EC2 has its own security rules that must be set. If you want to answer this question, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS has its own firewall and security group. You need to open the port there too.

For EC2, you can go to **Service** -> **EC2**  -> **Network & Security** -> **Security Groups** and open the port for the right group.